# Login Page Using Java Spring, NetBeans, and Derby

Tags: netbeans, authentication, derby

Does anyone have recommendations for a good article on how to add a login page to a NetBeans Java Spring Web application using a Java DB (Derby) database?  I want to store multiple the passwords for the login in the derby database, which will be accessed when a user attempts to sign in rather than have the passwords hardcoded in the code as most of the examples that I've seen seem to do.  I am trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this for real, not just for an academic learning exercise, be careful storing passwords.

It's extremely easy to do this incorrectly. Here's a few great resources:

- http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords
- http://throwingfire.com/the-history-of-password-security/

In terms of actually storing the data in Derby, passwords (once correctly processed as above) are just data to Derby.